# How to change the icon of an external EXE file using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to change a formerly generated EXE file's main icon using Delphi. The EXE file was also generated by me using Delphi. But I want the user to be able to change its icon.

I tried using UpdateResource function to change RT_GROUP_ICON and RT_ICON without success:

```
procedure UpdateExeIcon(Const IconFilename, ExternalExeFilename:string);
var
  Stream     : TFileStream;
  hDestRes   : THANDLE;
  lpData     : Pointer;
  cbData     : DWORD;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(IconFilename,fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    Stream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    cbData:=Stream.Size;
    if cbData>0 then
    begin
      GetMem(lpData,cbData);
      try
        Stream.Read(lpData^, cbData);
        hDestRes:= BeginUpdateResource(PChar(ExternalExeFilename), False);
        if hDestRes <> 0 then
        begin
          //if UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_ICON,PChar('1'),1033,lpData,cbData) then
          if UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_GROUP_ICON,PChar('MAINICON'),1033,lpData,cbData) then
          begin
            if not EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE) then RaiseLastOSError;
          end else RaiseLastOSError;
        end else RaiseLastOSError;
      finally
        FreeMem(lpData);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: When/where do you conclude it was "without success"? Which other steps are successful?

Comment: @AmigoJack The procedure certainly injects something, but it doesn't change the main icon.

Comment: The main icon from Windows perspective is the first one. Inspect the executable using a resource editor to see what has happened. As always, the key to solving a problem is to debug it.

Comment: Does refreshing icon cache help? https://superuser.com/questions/499078/refresh-icon-cache-without-rebooting

Comment: @W.Chang No, it doesn't work. Even tried changing filenames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple mistakes:

1. In `UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_ICON,PChar('1'),1033,lpData,cbData)` the `lpName` parameter works in two ways: `PChar('1')` will turn out as a text, while `MakeIntResource(1)` will turn out as a number. You want the latter variant, not the former.
2. For the resource type `RT_ICON` you have to provide the actual Icon **payload**, not an entire Icon **file**. Right now you do the latter, not the former. Look at how an Icon file looks like, then look at what the resource only has.
3. The resource type `RT_GROUP_ICON` is "only" an index describing existing `RT_ICON` resources and should be patched as per your updated Icon (unless width, height, colors, pixel depth and payload length are all the same). Filling in file contents here makes never sense.

[image: Resource Hacker: icon payload]

Above you see [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) displaying the raw bytes of the resource we want to update. `128` is the length of bytes in hexadecimal.

[image: HxD icon file container]

Above you see [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) displaying a whole Icon **file** - I selected the part where the first icon **payload** resides: starting at offset `26` with a length of `128` (both hexadecimal). Both byte sequences match.

If you do all that (using `MakeIntResource(1)` on `RT_ICON` and provide only the picture data of the Icon file) then you're fine - it worked for me fine: my EXE then displayed the new icon in Windows' Explorer (haven't executed it, tho). Updating the `RT_GROUP_ICON` should also be done, since I'm not sure up to where it seems to have no effect and when it suddenly becomes a problem. Viewing your files in a hex editor and your EXE in a resource editor will make you understand much better all the actions. Further reading:

- The [Icon file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)#Icon_resource_structure) (quite easy)
- The [RT_GROUP_ICON format](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120720-00/?p=7083) (almost identical to Icon files)

Comment: Thank you for your great help. Could you please provide a code sample for #2? I have no idea how I can provide a payload instead of the icon file.

Comment: I can't since I don't know which of the Icons in a file you want to read. Also "how to parse Icon files" should be a new question, not a comment.

Comment: Let's say I only work with 32x32 pixels 32 bit depth icon files (no multi-icon). A sample payload code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask a new question, stating what you achieved so far and where you fail - there are only advantages instead of treating comments like a chat.

Comment: 6 upvotes, yet @Andrzej won't accept it - was this question a combination of borrowed code and delegated homework after all?

Comment: Your help is appreciated but this answer is insufficient for future searchers.